# How to access Maven dependency artifact during the build process?

Tags: maven

I've got a build process which involves a very large zip file with lots of static data that I need to use during the `package` phase.

The file is so large that I can't put it into the source code repository, so the obvious solution is to install it in a private Maven repository and pull it in as a compile time dependency.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>very.big</groupId>
     <artifactId>file</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <type>zip</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

So far so good, however I still need to unzip and manipulate the contents of the file to build my module using either the Assembly plugin or the Antrun plugin.

Any ideas on how I can refer to the zip file from my POM? (Without hard-coding my local repository location of course.) Or more generally, how do I unzip a dependency into a specific directory under `${project.build.directory}`?

Comment: Usually by using a dependency with `<type>zip</type>` and may be an supplemental `<classifier>xyz</classifier>` depending on the method of how the zip file has been produced. You should start using a repository manager.

Comment: @khmarbaise The question isn't how to declare the dependency but how to access it from say an assembly descriptor, or the antrun plugin.

Comment: So we are not talking about a dependency so we are talking about an assembly descriptor instead. Within a descriptor you can use `<dependencySet>`...Furthermore you should update the whole question.

Comment: I'm happy with using `<dependencySet>` but the question still stands: how do I achieve what I described above?

Comment: I would use the dependency-plugin to resolve and unzip it (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) to a specific directory (something like _target/bigzip_), so that you can use its contents later with other plugins.

Comment: @Tome That sounds promising, I'll give it a go.

Comment: I often used it, in the same kind of needs. You might take caution about that dependency scope, to avoid it to be included transitively if that can happen.

Comment: @Tome It works perfectly, could you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Tome Fortunately this is just a standalone zip of data, so it won't have any transitive dependencies.

Comment: I was speakign about the module using it. If another module depends on that one, it will also pull the zip dependency, but most of the time, modules performing such work with artifacts are not dependencies of other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perform the following steps:

1. As you did, upload that item to a repository manager, and declare it as a dependency inside the POM needing to perform you work around it:

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>very.big</groupId>
        <artifactId>file</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>compile</scope> <!-- or another scope like provided/optional -->
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Use the `dependency:unpack-dependencies` mojo to resolve it and unpack it under a specific location:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.10</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
               <phase>package</phase> <!-- change it if needed -->
               <goals>
                   <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <includeArtifactIds>file</includeArtifactIds>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/bigzip</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Perform any needed work with other plugins, referencing the unzipped location (specified in `<outputDirectory>`)

Comment: Have the same answer but you were faster :) - upvoted

Comment: Eight spaces (rather than four) will get you code blocks under lists :-)

Answer (score 1):

On top of Tome's answer you could consider to use some kind of dependency repository (e.g. Archiva) in case this zip file is to be shared between developers. Thus you will all have the same shared resource and a common way to access it.

Comment: I should've been more clear but that is really what I meant by private repository, i.e. private to the development team.